# SharePoint 2010 Save site as template without content - file size exceeds 500mb

Tags: site-template

I am trying to save site as template WITHOUT CONTENT, and the result is an error that the site is too large to save as template. the size of template cant exceeds 524288000 bytes.

I have about 25 lists and 10 columns in each list.

I do not believe site is that big without data.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

according to the documentation ms:
[MaxTemplateDocumentSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebservice.maxtemplatedocumentsize.aspx) your are right, there is a limit to export templates

In this case use [Export-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx)

make sure to use the NoFileCompression flag

Good Luck

Comment: Can Export-SPWeb be used to create site without content, because I need that and not site with content?

Comment: No it doesn't have that option.
but, you can increase the size limit with this command:
stsadm -o setproperty -pn max-template-document-size -pv 550000000